# How to take the cumulative sum of data up to a specific date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I would like to find a formula that takes the cumulative sum up until a specific date specified. Ideally a formula that contains the date function so the user can select which date to have the cumulative sum of. For example:

[image: Cumulative sum excel example]

In this example I chose a specific date in the highlighted cell and the corresponding answer it should have using the correct formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `FILTER` if you have the newest version of Excel.

For example: `=SUM(FILTER($J$2:$J$5, $I$2:$I$5<=I8))`

Another way is to use `SUMIF`. For example: `=SUMIF($I$2:$I$5, "<="&I8, $J$2:$J$5)`

[image]